# Does Google Chrome officially work on Windows 7 64-Bit Yet?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, google-chrome

As soon as I jumped onto one of the beta releases for Windows 7, I tried to install Google Chrome. Being on a 64-bit installation it came up with a 'non-supported OS' or some error (can't remember).

Having a look around at the time I saw lots of posts/tips about just appending

```
--in-process-plugins
```

to the shortcut for chrome, after trying this and still not having luck, I found more posts including what seemed ones from the Chrome developers saying this was not wise and exposed a *security risk*.

So does anyone have a well sourced answer, as to what's holding up Win 7 64-bit support in Chrome, or better yet an "official" answer to say that it is supported in Win7 x64 RTM and works well now...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Before my W7 x64 computer broke, I was using Chrome as my primary browser. You didn't need to do anything special to install it.

This was not the case when the beta was first released, but the Chrome devs have since fixed the problem(s).

Answer (score 1):

Installing Chrome was the first thing I did after installing Windows 7 x64 on my work computer.  The (default) install completed without a hitch and it has worked flawlessly since.  I even switched it to the dev channel, and that seems to work fine as well.  So if there were any problems, they must have been fixed by late June.

Answer (score 0):

Non-64 bit apps work just fine under 64-bit Windows Vista/Windows 7. If you're having issues with Chrome, they're stemming from something else.

Comment: Not entirely true. Chrome had a known issue with the RC of Win 7 x64. Just because an application works on x64 Vista does not guarantee that it will work on 7.

Comment: I guess I never encountered it, in my running stable/beta/dev on Chrome throughout the different Win7 64-bit builds. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Running any x86 application under a Windows x64 operating system will start them in 32-bit emulation mode ("wow64"). So there should be no problem at all with normal applications. The only thing that may cause problems could be applications such as games which may not run in emulation mode.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 7 64 bit (Win7 x64 RTM) 
Download using the Standalone installer.. it works..

http://dl.google.com/chrome/install/195.21/chrome_installer.exe

This number may change *** /195.21/ ** depending on the version. This is the latest version as on date
- Vivx